# You have requested a non-existent service "twig" ERROR

Tags: php, symfony, twig

I have a problem in installing Twig in my project.

when i run `composer require twig` , the error appeared `In ContainerBuilder.php line 1024: You have requested a non-existent service "twig".` I tried it in my other projects and it works but in this specific project it doesn't. Im new in Symfony that's is why i see this so technical.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like Flex recipe isn't always working flawlessly.
Doing `composer require twig` adds only the following line to `config/bundles.php`:

```
Twig\Extra\TwigExtraBundle\TwigExtraBundle::class => ['all' => true],
```

You should add another line next to it:

```
Symfony\Bundle\TwigBundle\TwigBundle::class => ['all' => true],
```

So the end result in `config/bundles.php` should look like this:

```
return [
    ...
    Twig\Extra\TwigExtraBundle\TwigExtraBundle::class => ['all' => true],
    Symfony\Bundle\TwigBundle\TwigBundle::class => ['all' => true],
];
```